# SQLite: Database or Disk is full No modification is done in database

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite to handle database while running a simulation on supercomputers here. I am using MPI process to do multiple threading. I am keep getting error that says "database or disk is full" while passing any query to SQLite. I have checked the space quota and I have so much of the space available. I don't know why I am getting this error, so can you tell me what is causing this problem? I am not inserting or deleting anything in database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed

Answer (score 0):

[forking was the problem](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/69964/focus=69977)

Roger Binns wrote:

> a fork is happening after the database has
>   been opened inserted by the compiler (but not gcc) in order to make things
>   parallel.  If you do a fork after a database has been opened then you are
>   very likely to get this kind of error in addition to database corruption.
>    Ensure all open calls happen after forks.