# Error in inserting data into predefined sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my android app I have a pre defined database (created using sqlite browser and it is in .db format) which is in the assets folder. User should enter his/her details (name,dob,age,gender & bloodgrp)and click save button. When the user click the button entered data should be inserted into sqlite database. But after clicking the save button logcat shows following error.

```
10-22 06:47:47.931: E/SQLiteLog(795): (11) database corruption at line 50741 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-22 06:47:47.931: E/SQLiteLog(795): (11) database corruption at line 50780 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-22 06:47:47.941: E/SQLiteLog(795): (11) statement aborts at 3: [INSERT INTO EMPerson(Age,PersonName,BloodGroup,DOB,Gender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)] database disk image is malformed
10-22 06:47:47.951: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(795): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/my.easymedi.controller/databases/EasyMediInfo.db
10-22 06:47:47.951: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(795): deleting the database file: /data/data/my.easymedi.controller/databases/EasyMediInfo.db
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795): Error inserting Age=4 Years 8 Months 5 Days  PersonName=swe BloodGroup=A+ DOB=17-02-2009 Gender=Male
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at my.easymedi.db.DBHelper.insertIntoDatabase(DBHelper.java:221)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at my.easymedi.controller.AddNewPerson.onClick(AddNewPerson.java:203)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-22 06:47:48.481: E/SQLiteDatabase(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My save button code segment is:

```
case R.id.btnSave:
        personName = etName.getText().toString();
        date_of_birth = tvDOB.getText().toString();
        age = tvAge.getText().toString();

        int selected_rb_ID = genderGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();   
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_rb_ID);
        gender = rb.getText().toString();
        bloodGrp = spiBloodGrp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String data = personName + date_of_birth + age + gender + bloodGrp;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(personName);
        person.setDate_of_birth(date_of_birth);
        person.setAge(age);
        person.setGender(gender);
        person.setBloodGrp(bloodGrp);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME, person.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_DOB, person.getDate_of_birth());
        values.put(COLUMN_AGE, person.getAge());
        values.put(COLUMN_GENDER, person.getGender());
        values.put(COLUMN_BLOODGRP, person.getBloodGrp());

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        //dbHelper.createDataBase();
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
        if(dbHelper.insertIntoDatabase("EMPerson", values)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has been saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops ! Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dbHelper.closeDatabase();

        break;
```

My DBhelper class has a method called insertIntoDatabase.

```
public boolean insertIntoDatabase(String table, ContentValues cv) {
    try {
        myDatabase.insert(table, null, cv);
        Log.d("INSERT", "Information Saved");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("INSERT", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone plz explain what's going on and how can I solve this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: can you run an intergrity test and see if all ok? http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed

Comment: also, run a select statement at your table and see if all ok. if it doesnt throw exception

Comment: @Apostolos - intergrity test is ok.

Comment: @Ann18 can you retry with a newly created database? also have in mind that some older versions of android do not read sqllite databases of 1MB or bigger (i state it just in case :) )

Comment: I've checked with the database which is in the assets folder. What do u mean that newly created database?

Comment: insertIntoDatabase method returns true. It prints "INSERT: Information Saved" message.But it doesn't insert data into database.

Comment: @Ann18 could u try inbuilt sqlite or sqlite browser?

Comment: @Ann18 where is create DB.

Comment: @Karthikeyan I am using sqlite browser and my database is in assets folder.

Comment: @Ann18 recreate your database file and use this one. that's what i mean. create a new .db file, create your table etc and then use this new one.

Comment: @Apostolos I've created new database file and table also.But the error is still coming:(

Comment: did you find a solution, I have the same issue.. the insert statement works perfectly for some records, then it fails showing the same error you have here