# How can I update or install bolt.db on my local machine?

Tags: php, database, content-management-system, bolt-cms

I am using Bolt CMS, and I've downloaded my site from git repository and installed it on the local machine without any db. When I run it, Bolt creates new bolt.db. But I have my own file - bolt.db, if I replace the new file or just place this bolt.db in the folder app/database, there is an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 11 database disk image is malformed' in W:\home\localhost\www\opart2\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:92
Stack trace: #0 W:\home\localhost\www\site\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php(92): PDO->query('PRAGMA synchron...') #1 W:\home\localhost\www\site\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(931):
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->query('PRAGMA synchron...') #2 W:\home\localhost\www\site\app\src\Bolt\Application.php(116):
Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->query('PRAGMA synchron...') #3 W:\home\localhost\www\site\app\src\Bolt\Application.php(69):
Bolt\Application->initDatabase() #4 W:\home\localhost\www\site\app\bootstrap.php(50): Bolt\Application->initialize() #5 W:\home\localhost\www\site\index.php(24):
require_once('W:\home\localho...') #6 {main} Next exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 11 databa in W:\home\localhost\www\site\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractSQLiteDriver.php on line 84
```

How can I get my database? Can PhpmyAdmin be for help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing it correct, you can just replace the bolt.db with your own database, Bolt will only create a new one if it doesn't find it.

I think here you are running into a separate problem, your sqlite db file is corrupted possibly because you backed it up while it was being used. There's some more info about how to repair in this question: [SQLite3 database or disk is full / the database disk image is malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed)

As of the 1.6.x versions of Bolt you can also specify an alternate location for your Sqlite database. Within your config.yml file you can set both the path and the databasename. eg:

```
database:
    driver: sqlite
    databasename: mydb
    path: /path/to/folder
```