# Django admin and SQLite: database disk image is malformed

Tags: django, sqlite, django-admin, admin, malformed

I have developed a Django powered web-pages where I am storing pretty much all content inside a database, let's say sqlite.db

Django properly reads all information from the database and displays the webpage correctly.

Using the admin interface however (on the production server -> the development server coming with the pydev plugin from Eclipse is working fine) the database cannot be accessed. If I just copy the database file it tells me it cannot read and I don't even get the log-on screen to the admin app of django. If I change the file and directory permissions as suggested in many forums I am getting the admin login screen, however django returns the "DatabaseError at /admin/ - database disk image is malformed" Error.

I am using Django 1.6.5 and sqlite3 3.7.13

Any ideas?

EDIT: I found out that only the main page of the django admin interface is affected. I can navigate to the app settings with no problems.

Comment: I found out that the django admin server run on the target system (raspberryPi debian-weezy) does not work as well (database malformed). On windows it does

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed

Comment: Thank you joel for the hint, but the database works fine in my development environment and I am making sure not to copy a database in use. I will try to create a new database on my target system and then just copy the information

Comment: After reading more carefully I found a solution, thanks to joel. http://askubuntu.com/questions/30185/banshee-encountered-a-fatal-error-sqlite-error-11-database-disk-image-is-malfo did the trick! Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joel pointed out "[SQLite3 database or disk is full / the database disk image is malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed)" has a solution in its comment sections (https://askubuntu.com/questions/30185/banshee-encountered-a-fatal-error-sqlite-error-11-database-disk-image-is-malfo). Thank you Joel Goldstick for the help!

Answer (score 10):

Only three steps.

1. delete `db.sqlite3` and all migrations files
2. run `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: this is really helpful

Comment: That's fine if you don't mind deleting your database. We don't always have that luxury.