# Core Data store corruption, database sqlite is malformed

Tags: sqlite, core-data, malformed

I found quite a lot of questions and responses with solution on how fix the sqlite outside the app, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed). I wonder if there are any solutions people are using within the app?

One solution that I have seen been talked about is deleting the app and reinstall it. But in my case that is not really an option.

Comment: Is this a common problem for your app?

Comment: Not really, nevertheless is has appeared as an issue, and would like to address it since the data are important and I want to avoid cleaning the database if there is a way to fix it. 
I implement some of ideas such as saving before resigning the app etc. but still it would be nice to have some logic how to address the malformed database issue.

Comment: If the storage has eaten your data, it's gone; there is no guaranteed way of getting it back. Restore a backup from somewhere else.