# Python/SQLite3: random "Database Error: database disk image is malformed" when trying to attach a database

Tags: python, sqlite

In order to gather/merge data into a single main database (named `output_db`), I try to attach several input databases (one a a time), but some randomly fail to attach with "Database Error: database disk image is malformed":

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(output_db)
connection.execute("attach '" + dat_file_path + "' as input_db")
"Database Error: database disk image is malformed"
```

I don’t get any error when manually attaching the databases using DB Browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

I’ve tried checking the integrity of all files, vacuuming them, re-importing them from where they came, to no avail.

I’m limited to Python 3.6.8 and SQLite3 3.7.17, but I’ve tried with SQLite3 3.32.2 and it fails the same.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to work around that issue by following those steps from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed/5316540#5316540](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed/5316540#5316540%E2%80%AF) :

```
cd "${DATABASE_LOCATION}"
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 "${DB_NAME}" | sqlite3 "repaired_${DB_NAME}"
mv "${DB_NAME}" "corrupt_${DB_NAME}"
mv "repaired_${DB_NAME}" "${DB_NAME}"
```

I still have no idea what cause the error in the first place, but I’ve spent enough time on that issue so I’ll just go with this for the time being.